# Adding ECW support in GeoServer OpenGeo Suite?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, boundless-suite, ecw

I have installed opengeo suite 4.8 with GeoServer:

" **2.8-SNAPSHOT**

Git Revision5ba955074e0c5b78a5c9576dba955bec93008889

Build Date14-Jan-2016 20:47

GeoTools Version14-SNAPSHOT (rev 109456cbb2cf31ce318330bad5d0176e3d04e4a9)

GeoWebCache Version1.8-SNAPSHOT (rev 1.8.x/854b89c13d79df5a232c32245f956cfb70de56f5) "

I am trying to add ECW support to this version of geoserver but no luck; don't know where can i download the right plugin, and don't know if that is possible on this version of geoserver. I would like to add other plugins if its possible in this version.

Comment: Do you have a license from Hexagon for using ECW on server?

Comment: No, but i can use it on other geoserver version, through gdal

Comment: You are still not allowed to do that.

Comment: But i have it already there on the plugins folder, but it doesn't  show in geoserver.

Comment: Users are supposed to read the license. ECW read-only is free for desktops but use on server is not allowed. GDAL can't know if computer is used as a server.